How to pass context from a command to the callback in discord.py
Partially Finished Product
So, essentially, I am trying to create a discord bot that will allow a staff member to request a role. That request will then be sent to an admin-only text channel with a button for approve and a button for decline. The part that I am stuck on is getting the bot to automatically add the role when the Approve button is pressed.
My code so far:
class Request(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.value = None

    
    @discord.ui.button(label = 'Approve', style = discord.ButtonStyle.green, disabled=False, custom_id='Approve')
    async def approve(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
            member = interaction.user
            approve_embed = discord.Embed(title='Request Approved!', description=f'Approved by {member.mention}')
            button.style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray
            await interaction.response.edit_message(embed = approve_embed, view=self)
            self.value = True
            self.stop()


    @discord.ui.button(label = 'Decline', style = discord.ButtonStyle.red, disabled=False, custom_id='Decline')
    async def decline(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
            member = interaction.user
            button.style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray
            decline_embed = discord.Embed(title='Request Declined!', description=f'Declined by {member.mention}')
            await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=decline_embed, view=self)
            self.value = True
            self.stop()

@client.command()
@commands.has_any_role('Mod', '1253697387051094136')
async def roleadd(ctx, role: discord.Role, user: discord.Member):
    channel = client.get_channel(1253704722544853185)
    view = Request()
    await channel.send(f'**New Role Request!** \n {ctx.author.mention} requested to give {role.mention} to {user.mention}', view=view)
    await ctx.reply('*Your request has been submitted*')


You can pass the context from the command to the callback by passing information through the view's arguments.
In the Request view define one argument for the user whom you want to give the role and another one for the role itself and set both the arguments as the view's attributes.
You can then use this in the callback function to do your desired actions.
Here is your reformed code:
class Request(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, user_to_give_role: discord.Member, role_to_give: discord.Role):
        super().__init__()
        self.value = None
        self.user_to_give_role = user_to_give_role
        self.role_to_give = role_to_give

    @discord.ui.button(label='Approve', style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, disabled=False, custom_id='Approve')
    async def approve(self, button: discord.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        member = interaction.user
        approve_embed = discord.Embed(
            title='Request Approved!', description=f'Approved by {member.mention}')
        button.style = discord.ButtonStyle.gray
        await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=approve_embed, view=self)
        await self.user_to_give_role.add_roles(self.role_to_give)
        self.value = True
        self.stop()

    @discord.ui.button(label='Decline', style=discord.ButtonStyle.red, disabled=False, custom_id='Decline')
    async def decline(self, button: discord.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        member = interaction.user
        button.style = discord.ButtonStyle.gray
        decline_embed = discord.Embed(
            title='Request Declined!', description=f'Declined by {member.mention}')
        await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=decline_embed, view=self)
        self.value = True
        self.stop()


@client.command()
@commands.has_any_role('Mod', '1253697387051094136')
async def roleadd(ctx, role: discord.Role, user: discord.Member):
    channel = client.get_channel(1253704722544853185)
    view = Request(user_to_give_role=user, role_to_give=role)
    await channel.send(f'**New Role Request!** \n {ctx.author.mention} requested to give {role.mention} to {user.mention}', view=view)
    await ctx.reply('*Your request has been submitted*')


Thank you SO much. I've been at this for weeks now, and when I asked the exact same question in the discord.py Discord server, I was turned away because I didn't have a firm enough grasp on the fundamentals of Python (which is true). However, what they didn't see was the other 400+ lines of code I had already successfully written to serve other purposes, but this little nudge was all I needed to cross the (temporary) finish line. Thank you, again for your help!

Hello hackerman

@JohnDykstraJohnTyler no problem I'm happy to help
